# Validation on one of two Submit button only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 submit buttons in my MVC C# project.  First one is to Save and the second one is to Save and Post.  When Save is clicked I don't want to do any validation.  But when Save and Post is clicked I want to validate and make sure all fields are filled in. At the Save and Post click all fields are mandatory.  So being new to MVC C# I'm wondering what is the easiest way to do this and does anyone have any examples of how to do this?  Thank you!

Here is my view with the Save button and then the Save and Post button

```
@using Budget.Models
@model Budget.Models.Budget_Mod.Budget_GrpObj

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Prepare Budget</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "PrepareBudget", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <table id="budgettable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 100px; background-color:#7ac0da">Fund</th>
                <th style="width: 400px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Function</th>
                <th style="width: 2500px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Object</th>
                <th style="width: 600px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Department</th>
                <th style="width: 600px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Location</th>
                <th style="width: 400px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Project</th>
                <th style="width: 800px; background-color: #7ac0da; " align="center">@ViewData["prev_yr2_yr"]<br /> Budget</th>
                <th style="width: 800px; background-color: #7ac0da; " align="center">@ViewData["prev_yr1_yr"]<br /> Budget</th>
                <th style="width: 800px; background-color: #7ac0da; " align="center">@ViewData["Curr_yr_yr"]<br /> Actuals</th>
                <th style="width: 800px; background-color: #7ac0da; " align="center">@ViewData["next_yr_yr"]<br /> Proposed Budget</th>
                <th style="width: 1000px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Nature</th>
                <th style="width: 1000px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">The Need</th>
                <th style="width: 1000px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Impact If Not Funded</th>
                <th style="width: 1000px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Aligns to District<br />Strategic Goal</th>
                <th style="width: 1000px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Aligns to District<br />Priority</th>
                <th style="width: 1000px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Rationale or <br />Computation</th>
                <th style="width: 500px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Is this an<br />Investment<br />Request?</th>
                <th style="width: 1000px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">If this is an<br />Investment request,<br />please justify.</th>
                <th style="width: 800px; background-color: #7ac0da; ">Major Object Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:100px"></th>
                <th style="width:400px"></th>
                <th style="width:2500px"></th>
                <th style="width:600px"></th>
                <th style="width:600px"></th>
                <th style="width:400px"></th>
                <th style="width:800px"></th>
                <th style="width:800px"></th>
                <th style="width:800px"></th>
                <th style="width:800px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px"></th>
                <th style="width:500px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px"></th>
                <th style="width:800px"></th>
                <th style="width:1000px">Total Budget<br />Requested</th>
            </tr>


            @{
    string prevObject = "0";
    string prevDept = "0";
            }


            @for (var i = 0; i < @Model.budgetList.Count; i++)
            {

                if (@Model.budgetList[i].acct_object_type != prevObject)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="font-weight:bold">@Model.budgetList[i].acct_object_type</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="font-weight:bold">@String.Format("{0,14:c}", Model.budgetList[i].major_object_total)</td>
                        @if (@Model.budgetList[i].department != prevDept)
                        {
                            <td style="font-weight:bold">@String.Format("{0,14:c}", Model.budgetList[i].total_budget_requested)</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
                prevObject = Model.budgetList[i].acct_object_type;
                prevDept = Model.budgetList[i].department;
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].version)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].fy)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].acct_object_type)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].created_by)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].date_created)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].modified_by)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].date_modified)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].major_object_total)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].total_budget_requested)

                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        @Model.budgetList[i].fund
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].fund)
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        @Model.budgetList[i].acct_function
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].acct_function)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:2500px" align="left">
                        @Model.budgetList[i].acct_object
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].acct_object)
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        @Model.budgetList[i].department
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].department)
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        @Model.budgetList[i].location
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].location)
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        @Model.budgetList[i].program
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].program)
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @String.Format("{0,14:c}", Model.budgetList[i].prev_yr2_budget)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].prev_yr2_budget)
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @String.Format("{0,14:c}", Model.budgetList[i].prev_yr1_budget)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].prev_yr1_budget)
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        @String.Format("{0,14:c}", Model.budgetList[i].curr_yr_actuals)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].curr_yr_actuals)
                    </td>

                    @if (Model.budgetList[i].acct_object_type == "10000 Salaries" || Model.budgetList[i].acct_object_type == "20000 Employee Benefits")
                    {
                        <td align="right" style="text-align: right">
                            @String.Format("{0,14:c}", Model.budgetList[i].next_yr_proposed_budget)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].next_yr_proposed_budget)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].nature
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].nature)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].need
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].need)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].impact_if_not_funded
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].impact_if_not_funded)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_goal
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_goal)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_priority
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_priority)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].rationale
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].rationale)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].investment_request
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].investment_request)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Model.budgetList[i].investment_request_justification
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].investment_request_justification)
                        </td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td align="right" style="text-align: right">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.budgetList[i].next_yr_proposed_budget, "{0:0.00}")
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.budgetList[i].nature, new { cols = 50, rows = 3 })
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.budgetList[i].need, new { cols = 50, rows = 3 })
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.budgetList[i].impact_if_not_funded, new { cols = 50, rows = 3 })
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_goal, ViewData["goals"] as SelectList, new { @class = "dropdownSource" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_goal)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_priority, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "clsColumnNames" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_priority)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.budgetList[i].rationale, new { cols = 50, rows = 3 })
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.budgetList[i].investment_request)
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.budgetList[i].investment_request_justification, new { cols = 50, rows = 3 })
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" value="Save Data" name="SaveData" id="SaveData" />
    </p>
        <br /><br />

    if (Model.role == "Budget_Role" || Model.role == "Chiefs_Role") 
    {
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save and Post Data" name="SavePost"  id="SavePost"/>
        </p>
    }

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        <h3><a href="https://apecsreports.scsk12.org/Secure/">Back to Main Menu</a></h3>
    </p>
}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.freezeheader.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#budgettable").freezeHeader();
    })

</script>

<script>
    $("select.dropdownSource").on("change", (function () {

        var columnSelectBox = $(this).parent("td").next("td").find("select.clsColumnNames");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/PrepareBudget/GetPriorities',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { goals: $(this).find("option:selected").text() },
            success: function (str) {

                $.each(str, function (Value, Text) {
                    columnSelectBox.append('<option value ="' + Text + '">' + Text + '</option>');

                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve columns.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }));
</script>
```

And here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(Budget.Models.Budget_Mod.Budget_GrpObj list, string SaveData, string SavePost)
{
    string verClosed = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var session_user = User.Identity.Name;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(session_user))
        {
            session_user = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["username"].Value;
        }
        AuditTrailManager.Add(session_user, "Saving Budget ALL Data","All Data");

        list.user_id = session_user;
        PCN mod = new PCN();

        int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        if (month > 7)
        {
            list.curryr = DateTime.Now.AddYears(+1).Year.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            list.curryr = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SavePost))
        {
            var BPosted = BudgetListManager.PostData(list);
            list.deptSelect = BudgetListManager.GetByID(list.user_id).ToList();
            mod.fteList = PCNListManager.PostFTEData(list.deptSelect, list.user_id, list.curryr);
            mod.ptList = PCNListManager.PostPTData(list.deptSelect, list.user_id, list.curryr);
            mod.stipendList = PCNListManager.PostSTData(list.deptSelect, list.user_id, list.curryr);
            verClosed = "Y";
        }
        else
        {
            verClosed = "N";
        }

        using (REPORTS_DBEntities context = new REPORTS_DBEntities())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.budgetList.Count; i++)
            { 
                var version = list.budgetList[i].version;
                var fy = list.budgetList[i].fy;
                var fund = list.budgetList[i].fund;
                var acct_function = list.budgetList[i].acct_function;
                var acct_object_type = list.budgetList[i].acct_object_type;
                var acct_object = list.budgetList[i].acct_object;
                var department = list.budgetList[i].department;
                var location = list.budgetList[i].location;
                var program = list.budgetList[i].program;

                var c = context.SCS_BUDGET.Where(a => a.VERSION.Equals(version)).Where(a => a.FY.Equals(fy)).Where(a => a.FUND.Equals(fund)).Where(a => a.ACCT_FUNCTION.Equals(acct_function))
                            .Where(a => a.ACCT_OBJECT_TYPE.Equals(acct_object_type)).Where(a => a.ACCT_OBJECT.Equals(acct_object)).Where(a => a.DEPARTMENT.Equals(department))
                            .Where(a => a.LOCATION.Equals(location)).Where(a => a.PROGRAM.Equals(program)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (c != null)
                {
                    c.NEXT_YR_PROPOSED_BUDGET = decimal.Parse(list.budgetList[i].next_yr_proposed_budget.ToString());
                    c.NATURE = list.budgetList[i].nature;
                    c.NEED = list.budgetList[i].need;
                    c.IMPACT_IF_NOT_FUNDED = list.budgetList[i].impact_if_not_funded;
                    c.ALIGN_TO_DISTRICT_GOAL = list.budgetList[i].align_to_district_goal;
                    c.ALIGN_TO_DISTRICT_PRIORITY = list.budgetList[i].align_to_district_priority;
                    c.RATIONALE = list.budgetList[i].rationale;
                    c.INVESTMENT_REQUEST = list.budgetList[i].investment_request;
                    c.INVESTMENT_REQUEST_JUSTIFICATION = list.budgetList[i].investment_request_justification;
                    c.DATE_MODIFIED = DateTime.Now;
                    c.MODIFIED_BY = session_user;
                    c.VERSION_CLOSED = verClosed;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        } 


    System.Data.DataTable dtBudget = new System.Data.DataTable();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    string strFName = "BudgetData_" + list.user_id + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss") + ".csv";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFName);
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.Charset = "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SavePost))
    {

        System.Data.DataTable dtPCNfte = new System.Data.DataTable();
        System.Data.DataTable dtPCNpt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        System.Data.DataTable dtPCNstipend = new System.Data.DataTable();

        dtBudget = BudgetListManager.ToDataTable<Budget_Mod.Budgets>(list.budgetList);
        dtPCNfte = PCNListManager.ToDataTable<PCN.PCN_FTE>(mod.fteList);
        dtPCNpt = PCNListManager.ToDataTable<PCN.PCN_PT>(mod.ptList);
        dtPCNstipend = PCNListManager.ToDataTable<PCN.PCN_STIPEND>(mod.stipendList);

        Response.WriteFile(BudgetListManager.CreateAllCSV(dtBudget, dtPCNfte, dtPCNpt, dtPCNstipend, strFName));
    }
    else
    {
        dtBudget = BudgetListManager.ToDataTable<Budget_Mod.Budgets>(list.budgetList);
        Response.WriteFile(BudgetListManager.CreateCSV(dtBudget, strFName));
    }

    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    } 
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Use jquery validation

Comment: @Chandru I don't think that's gonna help him. If I understand correctly, he wants to skip validation in the server if the request came from one of the submit buttons.

Comment: One solution is you can create two model with different name with same properties. One is with validation and another one is without validation and on you `save and Post` button use model with validation. But make sure this is not at all good way.

Comment: You should maybe take a look on using Middlewares to accomplish that (if you use ASP.NET Core; there's also DelegateHandlers on ASP.NET < 6). You can intercept the request, see from which  submit button it came and then inform ASP.NET to skip validation.

Comment: @Andra What exactly you want to do or where you want to store data when click on Save button? Please post which code is not working for you.

Comment: Just posted my View and Controller so you could see. On Save button I just want to save what ever they have entered but on Save and Post I was to make sure they have entered something in every field before saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should POST in both cases to the server because you are saving data... just in "Save and Post" scenario you want to do validation.

Basically on the server you can differentiate which button was clicked. Here is the code that does that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About(AboutModel model, string save)
{
    // your button id/name is save - this value will be initialized only if that button is clicked
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(save))
    {
        // just save
    }
    else
    {
        // save and post... you can check for ModelState.IsValid like:
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // invalid model
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

And here is how `cshtml` form will look like so you can get idea on what is being done:

```
@model AboutModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Test Form</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="save" name="save"
                       type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input @* no id/name *@
                       type="submit" value="Save and Post" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Isn't this: `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty("save"))` always true? Should just be: `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(save))` ?

Comment: So, if I add the [Required] DataAnnotation to the fields in my model then they will be ignored if I don't check ModelState.IsValid?

Comment: @SivaGopal You are right, I've incorporated fix you are suggesting. Thanks!

Comment: @Andra Yes for that method/logic. But no if you are trying to save to database - database constraints still need to be respected... they are obviously there for a reason. So you need to save to different place. You can make another table without constraints. Or you can serialize Model to JSON and then save that on the server... so many alternatives, and of course - it's your call ;)

Comment: I tried this.....I added [Required] to each field in my model. and only checking ModelState.IsValid on Save and Post button. But when I click Save it immediately tells me required fields before it even posts back to my controller.  I set a breakpoint on  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Save)) and I'm not even getting to the breakpoint. Is there something else I am missing>

Comment: @Andra Try disabling client-side/unobtrusive validation.

Comment: Thank you!  That works great except when I Save and Post with blank fields I get no error messages.